# Need help in computing probability with multinomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, markov-chains

> Let $X=(X_1,...,X_k)$ is multinomially distributed with index $n$ $$X\text{~} \text {Mul}(n,p_1,...,p_k)$$ Let $1\leq i_1 <,...<i_l\leq k$ .Further we define the sequence $Y_1 =\sum_{j=1}^{i_1}X_j$,$Y_2 =\sum_{j=I_1+1}^{i_2}X_j$,...,$Y_l =\sum_{j=i_{l-1}+1}^{i_l}X_j$,$Y_{l+1} =\sum_{j=i_l+1}^{k}X_j$.Compute the probability $$P(Y_1=n_1,...,Y_{l+1}=n_{l+1})$$

I thought that $Y_i$ form a Markov chain but i realize that it is not clear.I am unable to solve this.Any ideas to solve this problem and how can we think of this problem ?

Comment: Hint: $(Y_j)$ is again multinomial, this time Mul$(\ell,q_1,\ldots,q_\ell)$, for some parameters $q_j$ to be computed.

Comment: @Did: Since i am not in touch with probability so i think i forgot all the basic probability ,i just need to use the above result of the question some where.Could you just remind me how to compute these $q_j$ ?

Comment: $Y_l$ actually is univariate and following a binomial distribution. To show this, you may consider to decompose each $X_j$ as a sum of indicators (Bernoulli trials)